# Query result Infinite Recursion on ManyToMany relationship on hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have a entity mapping like this:
[image]

**As you can see it is the bidirectional relationship and the team_users table has it own primary key and extra column - active.**

Key code in team entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<TeamUsers> team_users = new HashSet<TeamUsers>();
```

Key code in user entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<TeamUsers> team_users = new HashSet<TeamUsers>();
```

Key code in team_user entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private Team team;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User user;
```

I have a API which will return all team information, then I have service class like:

```
    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository teamRepo;

    public List<Team> listAll() {
        return (List<Team>) teamRepo.findAll(); 
    }
```

Then the chrome log me that I have a "undefined" value, and when I test it by postman it shows me the infinite loop value:
[image]

I want to figure out what is the best approach to fetch the data?
I want to all information that tells me the team situation, including team... users...active status , almost everthing.

Any suggestions?

### **update**

I tried to use @JsonIgnore on intermidate table :

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")
private Team team;
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User user;
```

but I won't get user information in that case and it avoid infinite loop:

[image]

What else I can do to get all information for teams?

Comment: You can try with [`@JsonIgnoreProperties`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39573255/4778343).

Comment: @StefanGolubović Hi can you explain a little bit more on which class I should apply this annotation?

Comment: Try ignoring `team_users` property on `team` and `user` property in `TeamUsers` entity, as you tried with `@JsonIgnore`.